# Select value from dropdown box but populate hidden column

Tags: excel

I have a set of unique IDs and names:

```
ID   NAME
aa   Jeff
bb   Matt
cc   Trung
dd   Trung
```

All IDs are unique.  Names are not.

On a worksheet I have a series of columns:

```
Date  Time  ID   Name  Value
1/1   1:30  aa   Jeff  123124
1/2   2:20  cc   Trung  12443234
```

Right now, a user will populate the ID field, the vlookup will return Name.

Is there a way to set up a dropdown on the ID cell that shows a concatenation of the ID and Name, but when selected, stores only the ID?

The idea is that the concatenated value that appears in the dropdown (Ex:  aa | Jeff) is more user-friendly that just "aa".

Comment: If names are not unique, how would drop down know which ID to return? Edit: in other words, you're doing this backwards. Have the name be the driver, not ID.

Comment: There is no guarantee... that's why I was hoping to use a concatenation to add some more information to the dropdown box.

Comment: I still feel like you're doing it backwards/can't wrap my head around the way you want to do it so sorry can't help :/

Comment: Thanks for looking.  I tried to edit for more clarity, so maybe that will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, hope my answer will help. If not, please tell me and I will try to improve it.

The code is inside the Worksheet

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    'Just use the frist part of the string, ID
    Range("I1").Value = Split(Me.ComboBox1.Value, " | ")

    'Optional, if you want to put the name using code.
    'If not, just use the VLOOLUP
    Range("J2").Value = Split(Me.ComboBox1.Value, " | ")(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim r
    Dim c
    Dim i
    Dim L
    Dim myRngID As Range

    r = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row 'the final row of the ID column
    c = Range("D2").Column ' the number of the column of the name

    Set myRngID = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(r, 3)) 'use only the ID range

    'Just to clean the ComboBox everytime to avoid duplicates
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
    L = Me.ComboBox1.ListCount
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To L
        With Me.ComboBox1
            .RemoveItem i
        End With
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Pupulate the ComboBox with the string {ID[space]|[space]NAME}
    For Each i In myRngID
        With Me.ComboBox1
            .AddItem i.Value & " | " & i.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

In the worksheet just this

[image: An image is worth a thousand words]

As you can see, the only formula in the sheet is in `J1`, the VlookUp. In `J2` the name is inserted using VBA. 
The ComboBox has any special property. Everything is in the code above.

The result is that the name is always taken from the ComboBox, and then no matter which one is selected, always will be the right one, as in the VlookUp.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try now, it looks perfect!

Comment: This is awesome!  It's exactly what I was needing.  I made a few modifications because there were some issues in activating other sheets and going back to the one with the boxes, because the CombBox values "changed" when they were refreshed to prevent duplicates.  This tried to overwrite the stored value.  However, the concept of populating the box and then filling in values on the sheet is exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This should work

1. Select the Cell on the Second Sheet (the one that will be the vlookup)
2. Go to the Data Tab > Data Validation > Data Validation
3. On Settings Select List > Click Source button at the right of the input box > Select Range from the first workbook [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYB83.png)
4. Now copy and paste that cell in the column on the second workbook